# flexslider nav and buttons doesnt work on firefox and chrome

Tags: wordpress, flexslider

The left and right buttons for the slider and the small buttons below the slider doesn't work when clicked. only works in IE but not on Firefox and chrome.

Also the images gets out of place when I re-size the browser window to a mobile phone size or tablet size browser.

this is the website http://amakris.com

Thank you

Comment: I'm seeing this issue in Chrome 32, but works in Firefox 27 on Windows 8.1.

Answer (score 2):

I have been driving myself crazy trying to find an answer to this very problem and I think I just have. It would appear that for the last almost 8 months that Flexslider 2.0 has had a known problem with touch devices. Personally I have an AIO touchscreen and just proved what I found. If you have a touch enabled device and visit any website using flexslider, including Woo's demo - you will notice that by using the "touch" device the slider buttons and navigation work perfectly, but not if you use the mouse.

Apparently there is a touch enabled feature in Chrome which may or may not be able to be turned off or programmed off with a little bit of code. See here: https://github.com/woothemes/FlexSlider/issues/351

It would appear that since flexslider is touch enabled, Chrome and AIO desktops or other touch devices signal to Flexslider to turn off the manual navigation because it is not needed.

I for one am happy that I can stop driving myself crazy now. Enough time has been wasted thinking about this.

I hope anyone else that finds this can rest easy to.